# Why does magento always change order status to pending after capture method

Tags: module, magento-1, payment

I am writing a payment module for our payment gateway,I am a java programmer and new to php,so please forgive for my poor php skill.
I have setted the new order status with pending and payment action with Authorise and Capture in my module.Then I want to change the order status to processing after payment approved in capture method with the code below

```
        $payment->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUCCESS);
        $order->addStatusToHistory(
            Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING,'payment success',false
        );
```

But I found that the order status always is changed to pending after the payment like this
[image]

How do I fix this bug?please help me,Thank you!

BTW,if I change the new order status with processing,even if the payment failed,the order still will be changed to processing,that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get help from here. >>>
http://www.atwix.com/magento/auto-invoice-and-custom-order-status-upon-checkout/
 Or
 http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-orders/automatically-invoice-ship-complete-order-in-magento/

Comment: I will read it right now,thank for your help.

Comment: thank you very much,it worked.the obsever is executed after the magento change the order to pending.